# Google form Apps Script to send email after form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, google-forms

I am trying to modify a google-form app script explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxgQr-jSu9o&list=PLU8ezI8GYqs4YntFNP9jf_rrZ0vJLSW2X&index=25) and [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/send-content-automatically-via-a-google-sheet-and-an-apps-script-c65d82284f5f).
this script is working fine without any problem.
But my problem is this script will not send email until one of the options is selected from the list of topics. And in my form there is no topic and any option.

### My requirement

I want a script that respond automatically even if no option from the list of **Topics** selected.

eg. the script should work without having a **Topics** option the the google-form.

Please help me to modify this script.
I will really appreciate your help.

### [Original Script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vyv-QcQ0wgaGNV7XklZI1jq95Cg_QVBq-o4rhTJqg00/copy)

```
var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HGXj6551jxUqFqxsuYMWovI0_nypSUPIdlc-RXf2pHE/edit?usp=sharing';
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Howdy, here is the content you requested';

var topicUrls = {
  'Nutrition': 'https://youtu.be/kCjDirATBos',
  'Reprogramming Habits': 'https://www.mindful.org/category/meditation/',
  'Urban Food': 'https://www.urbanfarm.org/',
  'Water Design': 'https://greywateraction.org/',
};

/**
 * Installs a trigger on the Spreadsheet for when a Form response is submitted.
 */
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}

/**
 * Sends a customized email for every response on a form.
 * 
 * @param {Object} event - Form submit event
 */
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;

  // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
  // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
  var timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
  var email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();
  var name = responses.Name[0].trim();
  var topicsString = responses.Topics[0].toLowerCase();

  // Parse topics of interest into a list (since there are multiple items
  // that are saved in the row as blob of text).
  var topics = Object.keys(topicUrls).filter(function(topic) {
    // indexOf searches for the topic in topicsString and returns a non-negative
    // index if the topic is found, or it will return -1 if it's not found.
    return topicsString.indexOf(topic.toLowerCase()) != -1;
  });

  // If there is at least one topic selected, send an email to the recipient.
  var status = '';
  if (topics.length > 0) {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
      htmlBody: createEmailBody(name, topics),
    });
    status = 'Sent';
  }
  else {
    status = 'No topics selected';
  }

  // Append the status on the spreadsheet to the responses' row.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var column = e.values.length + 1;
  sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(status);

  Logger.log("status=" + status + "; responses=" + JSON.stringify(responses));
}

/**
 * Creates email body and includes the links based on topic.
 *
 * @param {string} recipient - The recipient's email address.
 * @param {string[]} topics - List of topics to include in the email body.
 * @return {string} - The email body as an HTML string.
 */
function createEmailBody(name, topics) {
  var topicsHtml = topics.map(function(topic) {
  var url = topicUrls[topic];
    return '<li><a href="' + url + '">' + topic + '</a></li>';
  }).join('');
  topicsHtml = '<ul>' + topicsHtml + '</ul>';
  
  // Make sure to update the emailTemplateDocId at the top.
  var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL).getId();
  var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{NAME}}/g, name);
  emailBody = emailBody.replace(/{{TOPICS}}/g, topicsHtml);
  return emailBody;
}

/**
 * Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
 * 
 * @param {string} docId - The ID of a Google Doc to fetch content from.
 * @return {string} The Google Doc rendered as an HTML string.
 */
function docToHtml(docId) {

  // Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" +
            docId + "&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
}
```

### The Original Google-Form

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
  if (topics.length > 0) {
```

...with:

```
  if (!topics.length) {
    topics = ['(no topics selected)'];
  }
  if ((true)) {
```